# Horizontal navbar does not span entire page width when zoomed

Tags: html, css, navbar

While I know what my problem is, I have no idea what the solution should be. I have a navbar as such:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a...
    <a...
</div>
```

Along with the relevant CSS:

```
.nav{margin:0 auto;padding:10px 0;max-width:1280px;min-width:800px;width:84%;background:#000 url('../images/navBG.png') repeat-x;font-weight:bold;border-top:1px solid #BBB;border-bottom:1px solid #BBB;color:#FFF;}
.nav a{padding:10px;border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #555;}
```

At the moment, this provides a navbar of 84% width, but the background image does not extend beyond this width. The 'solution' here would be to wrap the nav div in another div/span that has the background properties, and a 100% width.

Of course, when you zoom in and the pixel-set min-width kicks in, the page becomes wider than 100%, so the navbar background stops past that length.

What I don't know is how to solve this. How can I have a navbar with a background that spans the entire width of the page, regardless of zoom, browser width, or resolution?

Comment: What's important about `width: 84%`? Why not just go with `width: 100%`?

Comment: Displaying any page at 100% width on larger monitors will make reading things a nightmare for certain page layouts. the point of the 84% is to put an 8% gap on either side of the page, so that it alleviates this issue. Adding a min and max width will then allow differently sized screens to either be at a wide enough width to stop things from being to small and potentially breaking the page, while at the same time allowing the gap to reduce to zero so that there is no gap on smaller screens that actually need the entire width.

Comment: Right, but setting 100% width on `.nav` will only make it fill the width of its container (whether that's `<body>` or something else), it won't actually increase the width of the page.

Comment: No, but if you have a minimum width set, small screens/widths or zoomed in pages will go past 100%. In essence, the navbar's 100% width will only be 100% screen width, even if there is horizontal overflow. move the horizontal scrollbar just a tiny bit, and you'll see the navbar background stops at only the width of the originally visible width...If that all made sense...